# Spring MVC @ResponseBody return list is not proper json reponse using hibernate

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Spring MVC @ResponseBody return list is not proper json reponse(no key & brace brackets) while using hibernate but getting proper json response if not using hibernate.

**DAO**

```
public List getStudentData(){
String hql= "select s.id, s.name, s.email from Student s";
Query query=  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
List list= query.list();
return list;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fetchAllData" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List studentContainer1(HttpServletRequest response){
    return ss.getStudentData();
}
```

**JSON(I am getting)**

```
[[1,"pratyush","pratyush.ankit@gmail.com"]]
```

**But I need response like below :**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Pratyush","email":"pratyush.ankit@gmail.com"}]
```

Comment: You also (1) should use generics, not raw types, and (2) use Spring Data JPA to autogenerate that DAO for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your DAO function to:

```
public List<Student> getStudentData(){
    String hql = "from Student";
    Query query =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    List<Student> list = query.list();
    return list;
}
```

The way you defined the hql query, it would return `List` of arrays in a form of [id, name, email]. And it would be impossible to convert it to a proper json later (the labels would be lost by that point). What you want is to make `getStudentData()` return `List` of `Student` objects instead.